# Reescribir parametros url multiples de php a m3u8 con .htaccess

Tags: php, php7, .htaccess

Necesito lograr esto por htaccess:

```
example.com/test.m3u8?id=query&post=1
```

O al menos esto:

```
example.com/test_id.m3u8?id=query
```

Esto reescribiendo PHP a m3u8 para que el player lo lea. Tengo esto:

```
-(\w+).m3u8?(.*)$
```

Pero no veo que funcione bien. Si alguien me ayuda, lo agradecería.

Comment: Explícate un poco mejor, pues ¿cual seria la URL que quieres que el usuario escriba y donde tiene que llegar internamente?  Al menos yo no lo he entendido, lo siento.

Comment: Bien. El usuario al escribir test_id.m3u8?query=1, ira a la misma info de test.php?query=1&post=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como dice el OP en los comentarios de la pregunta, si lo que pretendemos es que un usuario, al escribir esto:

```
test_id.m3u8?query=1
```

se dirija internamente a este script con estos parámetros:

```
test.php?query=1&post=1
```

se me ocurre que puede hacerlo de un par de formas.

A saber:

1. (Recomendada) Usar .htaccess con reglas Rewrite (el servidor apache debe tener instalado ese módulo para que funcione) para redireccionar `test_id.m3u8` al script `test.php`, y luego, dentro de `test.php` realizar el resto de trabajo para interpretar el QUERY_STRING recibido.

O sea, en .htaccess podría ser así de simple:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test_id.m3u8 test.php [L]
```

y después, dentro de `test.php` recoger el dato del QUERY_STRING gracias a [$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php) de este modo:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) and $_REQUEST['QUERY_STRING'] == 'query=1' ) {
    // aquí interpretar lo que sea necesario, por ejemplo:
    // $query = 1;
    // $post = 1;
    // y luego usar esos valores para realizar lo que se tenga que hacer
}
```

Esto creo que es lo más sencillo que podemos hacer y así el PHP tiene el control sobre el QUERY_STRING sin marear demasiado más al .htaccess, y con la flexibilidad que PHP nos puede dar en el manejo de esos datos.  Recuerdo que el archivo .htaccess se lee en cada petición al dominio alojado, y normalmente más de una vez por petición segun las reglas que tenga, por lo tanto tampoco es plan llenarlo de cientos de reglas por el coste en recursos que puede llegar a suponer.

2. Otra forma sería la siguiente, donde en el .htaccess no hacemos la redirección hacia test.php a menos que el QUERY_STRING esperado aparezca. En caso contrario no se hace nada.

Quedaría así:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} query=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^test_id.m3u8 test.php [L]
```

y ya dentro del test.php volveriamos a usar el código anterior para filtrar el QUERY_STRING de nuevo.

Comment: No habria una forma de reescribir una url con 2 parametros con htaccess donde id sea una variable y post sea un numero? O se recomienda mejor usar php para hacerlo de forma mas simple?

Comment: Para mi es mucho más sencillo manipular el querystring desde PHP que desde .htaccess.  No es demasiado habitual hacerlo desde .htaccess tampoco, aunque seguramente se puede, pero no le veo el sentido si al final vas a parar a un archivo PHP que puede manejar eso mucho más comodamente y sin afectar a todo el resto de páginas de la web que también tendran que leerse todas las lineas del .htaccess que agreges aunque no se cumplan las reglas que haya.

Comment: Piensa que todas las webs que tienen url amigables no usan el .htaccess para ello, sino que lo mandan todo a un index.php (u otro lenguage de desarrollo) que interpreta las peticiones y las gestiona desde alli en PHP (u otro).  Si quieres hacerlo de otro modo pues vale, pero como decia antes, no es lo habitual ni recomendable.

Comment: Ah, esta bien, gracias. Lo usare asi.

Comment: Si esta respuesta te ha servido recuerda marcarla como aceptada para que la pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente.  En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo cuando la respuesta cumple con la pregunta. Gracias por colaborar en el buen funcionamiento de este sitio. Saludos!